# How can I make a copy of a stack but preserve the original?

Tags: java

How can I make a copy of a stack but preserve the original using only `push`, `pop`, `peek`, and `isEmpty` methods from the Stack class? Is this even possible?

```
public static <E> Stack<E> copy(Stack<E> s){

        s2 = new Stack<E>();
        if(s.isEmpty())
            return null;

        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {
            E elem = s.peek();
            s2.push(elem);
            s.pop();
        }

        return s2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StackCopy sCopy = new StackCopy();

        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();

        s.push(1);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(3);
        s.push(4);
        s.push(5);

        s2 = sCopy.copy(s);

                System.out.print("stack1 = ");
                while(!s.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(s.peek() );
            s.pop();
        }       

                System.out.println("Stack 2 = ");
        while(!s2.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(s2.peek() );
            s2.pop();
        }


    }
```

Comment: You can have an intermediate data structure like an `array` that will hold the elements of `stack` temperately and then transfer them to your copy stack.

Comment: Sounds almost like you are playing Towers of Hanoi...

Comment: And as we all should know, Towers of Hanoi has O(2^n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would have to do is pop all the way down do the bottom and peek at it, storing each popped value somehow (into a dynamically allocated array?)(ArrayList in java?)

Then you would have to push the values back onto the stack and duplicate onto an additional stack.

stacks aren't generally meant to be duplicated as data structures.

If you have a choice and you want that functionality, you might consider using another data structure, such as a deque.

With a deque you can just take off of the top and copy to the new top, then put it back onto the bottom, and go through all of the items once.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: Im going to try a temp array, probably the best way to do it. I never even heard of a deque, really interesting. Thank you for the speedy help.

Comment: It is called a `queue` but `dequeue` is the method (verb) describing the behavior of removing an element from the end of the `queue` and returning it.